# How localize data in database in a ASP.NET Core MVC Web Application project

Tags: asp.net, model, localization, asp.net-core-mvc, globalization

I have implement the Globalization with resx file for all views in an ASP.NET Core MVC project, and that's work fine with 2 languages.
But now, I need add a feature for create objects in my web application in 2 languages.
For example, I have an "article" object, like a newspaper article.
When the user create an article, I will like to give him the opportunity to write the same article in the 2 languages.

I think create localized property for article object like :

- ArticleId
- ArticleTextEn <- text in english
- ArticleTextDe <- text in german
- ArticleCreationDate

Then manage with view model for check current language and display the correct data in the view...

What's the best practice in ASP.NET Core?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Since you create the artical object with fields for two different languages, I think you don't need to localize. Just judge the language of the current page, then get the corresponding articaltext from database.

Comment: Ok, but that's only an idea. Does it exist better way or another best practice?

Comment: It depends on your specific scene.